# Clean a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which basically contains of all strings in a .txt file. Now I'd like to clean the strings in the list of all commas, points, exclamation marks and so on.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
r = ""
import string

def find_word(filepath,word):
    doc = open(filepath, 'r')

    for line in doc:
        words = string.split(line) ##line.split() causes the same error
        words = [w.replace(["'",'`', '[',']','{','}','(', ')', ':', ',', '.', '!', '?', '"', ';'],"") for w in words]
        print words

find_word("pg844.txt","eBook")
```

And the traceback:

```
line 11, in find_word
    words = [w.replace(["'",'`', '[',']','{','}','(', ')', ':', ',', '.', '!', '?', '"', ';'],"") for w in words]
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: What are you expecting `string(string.split(line))` to do? Do you just want `words = line.split()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have deleted that. I originally had string.split(line).

Comment: With the same error message? Please edit to give a [mcve] and the full traceback.

Comment: I posted it in the original question.

Comment: Note that that's **completely different** to the error you originally asked about... Why on earth are you passing a list to [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?!

Comment: Well I don't know... I just want to get rid of all the punctuation in the strings in the list. The final goal is to write a code which finds certain words in the text. And therefore I have to get rid of all the punctuation.

Comment: *"Well I don't know..."* - stop [programming by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) and read the manual!

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to achieve; what I don't understand is why you thought that passing a list to `.replace` would help you do that. Have you considered reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I knew that replace does not work for lists but I did not really know how to solve the problem. Eugene Soldatovs answer helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` is method of string which return array of strings produced by splitting source string to pieces by some value (default is whitespace), so you should do:

```
words = line.split()
```

You can remove characters using regexp:

```
words = [re.sub('[\W_]+', '', w) for w in words]
```

Or without regexp:

```
words = [''.join(s for s in w if s.isalnum()) for w in words]
```

You can't pass list in `replace` method.

Comment: I tried this, but now there is a new error "TypeError: expected a character buffer object".

Comment: In IDLE, if I run the module.

Comment: Here's the traceback:

line 11, in find_word
    words = [w.replace(["'",'`', '[',']','{','}','(', ')', ':', ',', '.', '!', '?', '"', ';'],"") for w in words]
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Check line above, you should do: words = line.split()

Comment: You can't pass list to replace method, as you try to do. Check variants in my answer.

Comment: The one without regexp works!!! :D Thanks a lot! Now I have to move on to the next problems! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

s = "username:! test,:?"

s = ''.join([ c for c in s if not c in string.punctuation])

print(s)

username test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def find_word(filepath,word):
     def reg(w):
        if w.isalnum() or w == ' ': return w;
        else: return '';
    doc = open(filepath, 'r')
    lines = doc.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = ''.join(map(lambda w: ere(w), line))
        print words
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import re

def find_word(filepath):
    word = ""
    doc = open(filepath, 'r')
    for line in doc:
        word = (re.sub('[,.!:;?]', '', str(line)))
        print word

find_word("pg844.txt")
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.